# Incompatible types due to readonly

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a object containing a middleware property but cant get the types to work. It tells me that the two middlewares are incompatible because one of them is `readonly`. Is there a way to solve this? - thanks :)

**Example**

```js
type Middleware = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;
type Router = { middleware?: Middleware[] };

const router = {
    middleware: [() => null],
} as const satisfies Router;
```

**Error**

```js
type Router = {
    middleware?: Middleware[] | undefined;
}

Type '{ readonly middleware: readonly [() => null]; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'Router'.
  Types of property 'middleware' are incompatible.
    The type 'readonly [() => null]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Middleware[]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to remove the [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which makes the object literals `readonly`:

```
const router = {
    middleware: [() => null],
} satisfies Router;
```

Depending on your use case: you can also change the type `Router` by adding the utility type [`Readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype):

```
type Router = { middleware?: Readonly<Middleware[]> };
```

Though you are not able to call e.g. `push` on `router.middleware`.

Comment: Haha thanks! I though i needed the `as const` but the `satisfies` does the job for me - thanks :D